# How to symlink config files to home directory and make them editable via network share

Tags: linux, debian, symlink, samba

I want to make specific config files editable via a network share. This is a local system running on a raspberry pi which powers my home automation system. I am not worried about security.

How do you create a symlink in such a way that it is editable by another user?

What I have right now is a symlink but on my Windows machine when I open the file there is nothing in it.

Samba Config:

```
[pi_home]
path = /home/pi
writeable = yes
guest ok = yes
create mask = 0664
directory mask = 0755
force user = pi
```

Existing Symlink:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi   pi     29 Feb 28 14:21 mosquitto.conf -> /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

File to symlink (owned by a different user):

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mosquitto mosquitto 36825 Feb 28 14:16 /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a symbolic link (*soft* link), it does not contain the data of the target.
Thus said, when you access it from the outside, it is empty.

Try using a hard link.

Also, be careful when using hard links, since it is easier to screw up your system.

Personally I'd recommend using Chef or Puppet to edit this files and deploy the changes to your RaspberryPi.

Comment: even with a hard link it would not work as the `pi` user doesn't have permission to write to the file

Answer (score 0):

Samba (depends also on which version) allows to follow symlinks. Sometimes it is required to set the option *wide links* for example:

```
[global]
  unix extensions = no     <<<---- "unix extensions" unset or disabled

[lav]
  comment = blabla
  path = /LAV
  writeable = yes
  wide links = yes         <<<---- option to let a symlink go out of share
```

However, the access privileges still play a role, the link itself does not override those of the destination file (you see the symlink file permits everything to everyone, but it is not true). So, a hard link could help, as noted in another answer. But nobody prevents you to change the permissions of the files you would like to manage "remotely", if that is not a concern for you.

It is strange, though, that if you open a (linked file) remotely, you get an empty file. You should get an error instead.

The file you are trying to export:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 mosquitto mosquitto 36825 Feb 28 14:16 /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf

shows that only the user mosquitto (or root!) can modify it. Unless you use the right credentials on windows, you can not write to it (but you should be able to read it, if the link is set up properly). So, start to have success at least in reading, then you can play with credentials, user/group permissions, to make it writeable.